# Aggregating, filtering and sorting paged data if the data needs to be collected from various paged endpoints or sources

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'll try to put this in as general a way as possible, because I'll need a fairly general strategy to solve it.

The problem I have is that I have a series of properly paged endpoints, but the users need to see pages of that data across those three endpoints, aggregated on one page with proper filters sorting and criteria.  The way this issue is solved now it is to just do an exhaustive fetch of all the pages and use client side paging after bringing all the resources into a single list. This is generally easy but I'm looking to reduce the amount of data that's pulled in if 90% of the time if most of the data is on the first page.

For example, I have paged endpoints /A, /B, /C and I want to get a first page worth of data.  The simple scenario for first and last of course is to fetch the first page of each, and see if the first page count is of the total number of items I need, and just do client-side sorting.  The problem is as I go forward several pages, I can't really get the proper state of what is fetched without somehow coordinating that with a client-side store of the existing page data.

My first instinct is that on the first page, I just continue to fetch from the endpoints, based on the counts, and when I get enough for the page, I keep that stored, and keep track up to which items I have used in the aggregated page.  So if I want a page of 10 items by a specific criteria, I make a call to those endpoints with the same criteria, and /A endpoint gives me page 1 to make 5 items, /B gives me 2 items, and /C gives me 5 pages to make  items, I deliver those to the client, keeping track of the page numbers and data of each of those page, do the proper ordering for that first page of aggregated data, keeping the leftovers for the next page call.

So essentially the first page would be a simple call, and any calls after that are just sequentially building up the data, while if a user just wants to fetch X page, you'd have to do the exhaustive build-up of page 1-X.

Is there something a little more intuitive, or is simple exhaustive aggregation the easiest way to coordinate that between client and service?